# How to extract pattern numbers from raw text

Tags: android, regex

I have text like `300..—1234 5678 9012.—..0000-040.`

How i can extract the numbers `123456789012` only?

I want to get numbers with pattern **numbers+space+numbers+space+numbers** only.

This is what i tried after getting `1234 5678 9012` only.Hope you understand my question.Thanks in advance

```
String text = item.getValue().trim();
char[] charArray = text.toCharArray();
String f1 = String.valueOf(charArray[4]);
String f2 = String.valueOf(charArray[9]);
if (item.getValue().length() == 14) {
   if (f1.equals(" ") && f2.equals(" ")) {
       String input = text.replace(" ", "");
       if (input.matches("[0-9]+") && input.length() == 12) {
          Log.i(TAG,input);
          }
       }
     }
```

Comment: Write a Regex for that specific pattern.

Comment: `if (f1.equals(" ")` is false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For you:**

```
 String text="300..—1234 5678 9012.—..0000-040";
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+\\s[0-9]+\\s[0-9]+");
 Matcher m=p.matcher(text);
 if(m.find()) {
     System.out.println(m.group(0).replaceAll(" ",""));
 }
```

Comment: The pattern will generate a lot of false positives, it will match two spaces for example. You should use something more robust, something like `\\d{4}\\s\\d{4}\\s\\d{4})` or `(\\d{4}(\\s\\d{4}){2})`

Comment: @Titus How will it match **two spaces**? Can you please explain? As per the RegEX it's supposed to match only **one** space

Comment: `*` means none or as many as possible. At least use `+` instead of `*`

Answer (score 0):

For given input, below should extract **numbers+spaces+numbers+spaces+numbers** but you would need to improve it by testing it against all possible data points you have.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Regex {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data = "300..—1234 5678 9012.—..0000-040.";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^0-9].([0-9 ]+)[^0-9].");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            // use replace(" ", "") only if you want to remove spaces
            // from the resultant string numbers+spaces+numbers+spaces+numbers
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1).replace(" ", ""));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it should now, but again it needs to be tested with all possible data points and improved as needed

Comment: According to what OP asked the pattern should be **numbers+space+numbers+space+numbers**